# Instead of foreach loop, how can I use in_array()?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

In codeigniter, in my controller file, I fetch data from model. To validate the results I use foreach loop and there is no problem. But instead of using foreach I want to use in_array() to control if variable is in database result array or not . Here is code :

```
function _remap($method,$params = array()){ 

//in construct, I use $this->model
if (isset($params[0])) {

    $this->db->distinct('*****');
    $this->db->from('*****');
    $this->db->where('****',****);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if (in_array($params[0],$query->results())) {
        echo "in_array works";
    }
}
```

But not echoing anything. How can  I do it?Thanks.

Comment: Does `.get()` return an [`object` or `array`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select)?

Comment: It returns query result as an array of objects. Use `result_array()` to return a pure array and then try using `in_array`

Comment: return object... Ohhh... In object I can not make it work, can I?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) you could use `result_array()`. Otherwise you will get back an object. Of course you cannot use `in_array` for an object.

Also according to the manual you could change your code to

```
if (in_array($params[0], $query->first_row('array')) {
  // ...
```

Comment: I wonder why this was downvoted? Anyways, I wonder the parameter isn't just put the in query?

Comment: Yeah, I am wondering too. But you could help and make justice :)! I have no idea about codeigniter, I just used my general programming senses (and Google)

Answer (score 1):

The **[in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)** is just to be used for only checking a value in the value-list 
e.g. array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");

**[in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)** wont work for your situation, because it returns object array.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to write a helper method, that does the job you want and returns True or False. Information on how to do it can be found [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html)